# Saving dialog boxes jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-dialog

I am implementing Sticky Notes using jQuery ui Dialog Box. So on a button click a dialog box is opened which covers full window size and inside that box is a button to add notes (which are dialog boxes of small size).

Now I want to save the notes added for every user. So I want when the user comes back again when dialog box is opened the previous notes (dialog boxes) are present there.

How can this be achieved??

Comment: Not possible with "ONLY" jQuery.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking about. Are you asking about how you could create the dialog boxes, or how to store the information? If it's storing something client-side, look up cookies and localstorage. If its serverside, you need to code it in your server.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent: Yeah the `content` of notes will be saved in DB, I am not clear about how dialogs boxes are opened already with the saved content loaded?

Comment: @bvx89: I am asking about creating dialog boxes. I will be able to get content from DB

Comment: Ok if you have already saved them then load the data from the db and create those dialogs then you can call them as `$('DIALOG_ID').dialog();` for each dialog OR `$('DIALOG_ID1, DIALOG_ID2,...').dialog();`  and wrap these in `$(document).ready{ });`

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly an answer to your question, mostly since you haven't provided any code for us to review, but things to consider when you're creating this functionality. There are multiple ways to go about solving it, but I'm not sure what's best for your application.

You can solve it by having the content of a users note being put on the page, but hide it from plain view until the user opens it. However, to save the state of the dialog, you either need to perform a POST on the page itself or perform an AJAX-request to the server to store it through an API. The latter is the preferred way to do it, as you don't need to refresh the whole page.

Let's say you do make an API to POST notes, but, if you already have an API to store the information, why not create an API to retrieve the information as well? This API has to be developed on the server, mind you.

Now comes the security part. Does your site require a login? If so, make sure that the current user is only allowed to GET/POST notes that they have written. If your site doesn't have a login, it's probably better if you store it in the clients cookies/localstorage instead of a DB so that they can't manipulate other peoples notes.

It's also probably a good idea to note what kind of server you're using when asking these questions, since you're talking to a database.

---

Answer (score 0):

Whenever user access the page, get the notes which are added for that user and assign to notes(div). This should happen in document.ready.  It will display the notes on dialog for the user if any.